# Using Ninject WhenInjectedInto

Tags: ninject

I'm trying to do the following:

```
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>>().WhenInjectedInto<OrderRepository>()
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>>().WhenInjectedInto<InvoiceRepository>()
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>>().WhenInjectedInto<PayslipRepository>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

What I want to logically happen is that a single instance of `UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>` is created for the request, and injected as `IUnitOfWork` into any of `OrderRepository`, `InvoiceRepository` or `PayslipRepository`.

Instead what is happening is that a **new instance** of `UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>` is created for each of the repositories.

I think if I replace the `IUnitOfWork` constructor paramter on those repositories for new 'dummy' `IOrderUnitOfWork`, `IInvoiceUnitOfWork` and `IPayslipUnitOfWork` interfaces that simply inherit `IUnitOfwork` and bind against those in Ninject's config then it should work, but I don't want to create empty dummy interfaces just to get Ninject working :(

I was looking for something like:

```
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>>().WhenInjectedInto<OrderRepository, InvoiceRepository, PayslipRepository>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

but that doesn't exist, and I couldn't find any chainable methods to get the same working either.

Your help much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try making a new UnitOfWork and bind it IUnitOfWork as a constant:

```
    UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext> work = new UnitOfWork<OrderDbContext>;

    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToConstant(work).WhenInjectedInto<OrderRepository>().InRequestScope();

    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToConstant(work).WhenInjectedInto<InvoiceRepository>().InRequestScope();

    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToConstant(work).WhenInjectedInto<PayslipRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: That will cause you to have one single UnitOfWork for the whole application lifecycle which is obviously not wanted.